# Rotate first PCA dimension parallel to an external variable

Tags: r, pca

I want to rotate my ordination so that the vector of an external variable lines up with the first dimension. When using an MDS as the ordination, I would use `MDSrotate` from vegan. Is there a way to do the same thing for a PCA?

Here is some dummy data.

```
df1 = data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,5.5,5,2), B=c(2,2,2,2,0.5,1), C=c(1.5,0,0,2.1,3,1), D=c(0.2,1,2,1,0.8,2), E=c(0.4,0.6,0.2,1.1,2,3))
env = data.frame(one=c(1.1,0,0.2,2,2.8,1.1), two=c(2,1,1,1.2,0.3,2))
pca <- rda(df1, scale = TRUE)
summary(pca)
biplot(pca, scaling = 3)
(fit1<-envfit(pca, (env), perm = 999))
plot(fit1)
```

[image]

I want to rotate the scores so that 'one' lines up with PC1. Is this possible? I've searched for a long time and can't find anything that appears to be equivelant to `MDSrotate`. Thank you